# Scraper does not return all images. Thinking it's because it is not async. How to make a for loop work asynchronously in a range?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I have a Python script that should scrape images from the website. But for some reason it does not return all the images. I have a suspicion that is because the for loop is not async. However, how would one use an async function with a for loop in a defined range?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path  import basename

def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text

for i in range(1, 80):
    string_i = str(i)
    htmldata = getdata("https://www.coingecko.com/en?page=" + string_i) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
    for item1 in soup.select('.coin-icon img'):
        link = item1.get('data-src').replace('thumb', 'thumb_2x')
        raw_name = item1.get('alt')
        name = raw_name[raw_name.find('(') + 1:-1]
        with open(basename(name + '.png'), "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out I can simply use `time.sleep()` function from `time` module to achieve asynchronity by adding `import time` at the beginning of the code and  `time.sleep(1)` at the end of the loop.